# How to generate multiple characters at once in Tkinter Entry widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am in the process of learning python and tkinter. I am trying to generate multiple random chars with a click of a button. I have gotten most of it but I am only able to generate one char at a time.

```
import random
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%&amp;*1234567890"

def genRanNum():
    for i in range(15):
       text.set(random.choice(characters ))

text = StringVar()
ranNumEntry = Entry(textvariable = text)
genButton = Button(text = "Generate", command = genRanNum)
ranNumEntry.pack()
genButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `ranNumEntry.insert(END, random.choice(characters))`

Comment: You are rewriting each char with new char in the iteration 15 times. Use `text.insert` instead of `set`.